# Why does starting a new Task get invoked on the UI Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

```
Task t = new Task(() =>
{
    //I would expect this to be on a worker thread, but it's not!
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});

Task test = new Task(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
});

test.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    //Do some UI Updates here, but also start another Task running.
    t.Start();
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

test.Start();
```

Why does `t` gets invoked on the UI Thread. I understand that I created a continuation `Task` against `test` which correctly gets called on the UI thread, but I am then starting a new task running. Now I know I could get around this by specifying `TaskScheduler.Default` as an overload method against `t.Start`, but why does a new `Task` get started on the ui thread?

Comment: General tip: There is no reason to ever use a task constructor yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but why does a new `Task` get started on the ui thread?

Because unless specified otherwise calling `Start` on a task schedules the task on the current `TaskScheduler` which in your case is a just facade over the UI thread's `SynchronizationContext` that you created using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

> Starts the `Task`, scheduling it for execution to the current `TaskScheduler`.

From [Task.Start Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you want that task to be scheduled on a different `TaskScheduler` than the current one you can pass it as a parameter:

```
t.Start(TaskScheduler.Defualt);
```

---

Note: There's almost no case imaginable that using `Task.Start` is the best solution for. You should probably rethink this avenue.

Comment: For further reading see Stephen Cleary's blog post "[StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)", specificly the section "Why Not to Use Task.Factory.StartNew". It talks about `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Start` but the underlying issue (scheduling the task for the current task scheduler inside a `ContinueWith`) is the same.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. At which point am I ever changing the TaskScheduler? I tell the continuation to run on the UI Thread. But I never tell `t` to run on the UI Thread.

Comment: @William You schedule the continuation on the `TaskScheduler` you created with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. This scheduler is the current scheduler when the continuation runs. So when you call `Start` `TaskScheduler.Current` is your special scheduler that posts tasks to the UI thread.

Comment: It makes sense. But the method `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` never suggests (from it's name only) that it should ever changes any state, but I guess it does. Thanks for answer

Comment: @William no no.. it doesn't. What "changes the state" is the fact that you explicitly schedule a task on a specific `TaskScheduler`. When you do that.. the task will run on that scheduler, that scheduler will be the current scheduler and will be stored in `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Comment: @William The fact that this scheduler happens to be the one created using `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` doesn't matter. It only specifies that the UI thread will be the one running these tasks.

Comment: @usr Can't argue with that. Added a disclaimer to the answer.

Comment: @i3arnon retracted comment because Task.Factory.StartNew also uses the TaskScheduler.Current and this does not solve the problem. Still good advice but less applicable. The TPL is full of these hidden traps like global state and reentrancy. Shame.

Comment: @usr not really a "hidden" trap since it's explicitly documented to do exactly that. Not the most intuitive default for what people want to do these days, but when the TPL was created there were different use cases that were considered. And honestly if you're using concurrency that's the least complex part of it and with .NET 4.5.2 we don't even have to write our own extension method any more because there's Task.Run.

Comment: @Voo `Task.Run` was added in .Net 4.5

Comment: @Voo the key point is that different use cases were in focus, yes. The samples back then all were CPU bound problems such as Mandelbrot and such. In those problems all TPL choices make sense, yes. Of course, 99% of "business code" does not do that...; There is a Github issue to remove reentrany by default from the TPL but according to the response there do not seem to be plans to address this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `Task.Start` method. Also, if you want to delay a task use `Task.Delay` like this:

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) //Wait 1 second
    .ContinueWith(t => DoSomeUIWork(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()) //execute something on the UI thread
    .ContinueWith(t => DoSomeBackgroundWork()); //Then do some background work
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, also StartNew would have the same behavior.

Comment: But this is going to start the task running immediately, which is not the behavior I want.